# Sync Pandora on multiple devices

Tags: audio, streaming, audio-streaming, pandora

I am looking for a way to sync my Pandora stream across my PC, iPhone and Roku box?  Has anyone done this before?

Comment: What OS and release are running on the respective machines?

Comment: Win 7 and iOS 7(i think)